# Encoding not working when trying to Upload to a web service

Tags: c#, webserver

Hi I am trying to send a data up to a web service via a WebClient but it seems to be incorrectly passing through the password field. Here is the code below for my WebClient:

```
 using (var client = new WebClient())
        {

            client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

              var response = client.UploadString(string.Format(SendToServiceURL + "api/SendRequest?Id={0}&product={1}&password={2}", Id, Product, Password),
                        "POST");

            return response;
}
```

The password before sending is - `GVg4Vs2<)/BFkU(u%Be%C:{<^9`

However the password when received by the service is - `GVg4Vs2&lt;)/BFkU(u�%C:{&lt;^9`

I have also tried making use of the HTTP utility pack `HtmlEncode` feature as shown below but that only returned `GVg4Vs2`.

(Note I just substituted `Password` in my original code for the `encodedPassword` variable below)

```
var encodedPassword = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(password);
```

Does anyone have an idea of why this is or a possible workaround?

Comment: You need to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` instead of `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`. But preferably you shouldn't put a password in the query string at all but make it part of the post data.

Comment: I will try `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` now and yes I understand that this is merely a test project for me at present as im not too familiar with WebClients. Thanks

Comment: Yep thats works grand thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` instead of `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode`.

`HtmlEncode` turns `<` into `&lt;` which means everything after `&` is a new query string parameter.

`UrlEncode` makes sure all the "weird" characters can be passed correctly as a query string parameter: `GVg4Vs2%3c)%2fBFkU(u%25Be%25C%3a%7b%3c%5e9`

But preferably you shouldn't put a password in the query string at all but make it part of the post data or even better use a proper authentication mechanism for the webservice call.